# How to pass the props value with @update emit function on q-radio component Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I want to create a single component with 3 q-radio then listen to the value of props in a parent component but it doesn't work.

The modelValue is sent by the props and the @update function emits the value.
When I click the radio button, the console log correctly receives the value but the q-radio component as not displayed is checked.
I get the message: 'Missing required accessory: "modelValue" ', why?
The modelValue as prop is sent by the parent component, right?

The code of my q-radio components:

```
<template>
  <div class="row content-center justify-around">
    <div>
      <q-radio
        val="walking"
        @update:model-value="emitVal"
      />
      <q-icon name="directions_walk"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <q-radio
         val="cycling"
         @update:model-value="emitVal"
      />
      <q-icon name="directions_bike"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <q-radio
         val="driving"
         @update:model-value="emitVal"
      />
      <q-icon name="directions_car" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
  name: "TravelChoice",

  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods:{
    emitVal(value){
      this.$emit('update:model-value',value)
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

And the code from my parent page:

```
<template>
  <TravelChoice :modelValue="choice" v-model="choice" />
</template>

<script>
  import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue"
  import TravelChoice from "components/button/TravelChoice.vue"

  export default defineComponent({
    name: "Home",

    components: {
      TravelChoice
    },

    setup() {
      return {
        choice: ref("walking")
      }
    },

    watch: {
      choice(val){
        console.log(val)
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```